# Azure Data Factory - I cannot see ADLS Gen1 Structured stream that I configured when adding it as a source

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I configured some ADLS Gen1 Structured Streams in ADF studio. When I try to set them as a source in a copy activity I don’t see them in the filter though I’m able to see RestSink that I configured. What am I missing?

Comment: Correct me if wrong, issue is that you are not able to list the ADLS Gen1 Source Dataset in the CopyActivity Source ?

Comment: Yes, I’m not able to see that in the ADF studio UI when I try to create a a copy activity.

Comment: Have you tried publishing the changes once

Comment: Any specific reason you opt ADLS Gen 1 over Gen2 ?

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Generic issue, I am able to reproduce without any issues. Kindly refresh browser and clear cache to rule out any browser related issues.

ADLS Gen 1 is supported as source and there appears to be no documentation on any similar limitations.

Refer: [CopyActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) and [ADLS Gen1 Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store?tabs=data-factory)